# How to parse XHTML in Velocity manager?

Tags: java, spring, velocity

I want to parse some text similar to the below example:

```
&lt;p class="MsoPlainText"&gt;&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;
This is Test Data ,What? To devlop this functionality.
Read more information&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;&lt;
a href="http://www.wikipedia.com"&gt;
more information&lt;/a&gt;&amp;nbsp;
Something I am doing wrong here.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

This content contains some tags. I am holding all this content in string variable `xmlToPlainText` and I am accessing it into Vm file as `$xmlToPlainText`.

Can anyone help to parse content like this in java?

Comment: Have a look at JSoup: https://jsoup.org/

Comment: Think about it. Are you really sure you want to parse that using velocity? A better idea would be parse that and put the parsed object instead.